# Timeout Error when connecting to an Arduino Nano BLE 33 using Python bleak

Tags: python, arduino, timeout, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect my Arduino Nano BLE 33 to my windows 11 laptop over Bluetooth so that the voltage running through a single pin on my Arduino can be wirelessly read by my laptop. I'm trying to do this using the bleak Python package.

When the Python code is executed, it is able to successfully scan nearby devices including my Arduino as it appears in the terminal when printing the names of the nearby devices. However, when it comes to connecting, I get the following error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexg\PycharmProjects\GBDP\venv\lib\site-packages\bleak\backends\winrt\client.py", line 436, in connect
    self.services = await self.get_services(
  File "C:\Users\alexg\PycharmProjects\GBDP\venv\lib\site-packages\bleak\backends\winrt\client.py", line 666, in get_services
    await FutureLike(self._requester.get_gatt_services_async(*srv_args)),
  File "C:\Users\alexg\PycharmProjects\GBDP\venv\lib\site-packages\bleak\backends\winrt\client.py", line 1097, in __await__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexg\PycharmProjects\GBDP\BLE scanner.py", line 23, in <module>
    asyncio.run(client_connect())
  File "C:\Users\alexg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\alexg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\alexg\PycharmProjects\GBDP\BLE scanner.py", line 14, in client_connect
    async with BleakClient("c7:5a:cc:5e:59:69") as client:
  File "C:\Users\alexg\PycharmProjects\GBDP\venv\lib\site-packages\bleak\__init__.py", line 491, in __aenter__
    await self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\alexg\PycharmProjects\GBDP\venv\lib\site-packages\bleak\__init__.py", line 531, in connect
    return await self._backend.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alexg\PycharmProjects\GBDP\venv\lib\site-packages\bleak\backends\winrt\client.py", line 392, in connect
    async with async_timeout(timeout):
  File "C:\Users\alexg\PycharmProjects\GBDP\venv\lib\site-packages\async_timeout\__init__.py", line 129, in __aexit__
    self._do_exit(exc_type)
  File "C:\Users\alexg\PycharmProjects\GBDP\venv\lib\site-packages\async_timeout\__init__.py", line 212, in _do_exit
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
```

The Arduino is correctly advertising the services and characteristics as it has no problems connecting and advertising to the nrf Connect app on my phone.

This is the code uploaded to my arduino nano ble 33:

```c##
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>

//Creating service VoltageRead
BLEService voltageRead("e3ddae28-87d3-4c18-89bd-3dde005d4a09"); 

//Creating string characteristic with its UUID
BLEStringCharacteristic volt_char("c677b455-b74c-454a-ac95-144dae0d412a",BLERead, 13); 

int voltagePin = 5;
float voltage = 0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  if (!BLE.begin()) {   // initialize BLE
    Serial.println("starting BLE failed!");
    while (1);
  }

  BLE.setLocalName("NanoBLE33");  // Set name for connection
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(voltageRead); // Advertise service
  BLE.setAdvertisedServiceUuid("e3ddae28-87d3-4c18-89bd-3dde005d4a09");
  voltageRead.addCharacteristic(volt_char); // Add characteristic to service
  BLE.addService(voltageRead); // Add service
  
  BLE.advertise();  // Start advertising
  Serial.print("Peripheral device MAC: ");
  Serial.println(BLE.address());
  Serial.println("Waiting for connections...");
}

void loop() {
  BLEDevice central = BLE.central();  // Wait for a BLE central to connect

  // if a central is connected to the peripheral:
  if (central) {
    Serial.print("Connected to central MAC: ");
    // print the central's BT address:
    Serial.println(central.address());
 
    
   

while (central.connected()){
    // read voltage from the voltage pin
    voltage = analogRead(voltagePin);
    //converting analogue to temperature equivalent
    Serial.print("Voltage =");
    Serial.print(voltage);
    Serial.print("mV");
    Serial.println();
    delay(2000);
    } // keep looping while connected
    
    // when the central disconnects, notify the user
    Serial.print("Disconnected from central MAC: ");
    Serial.println(central.address());
  }     }
```

The code used on my laptop to try and connect to the arduino:

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner, BleakClient

# defining the main scanning code which prints a list of the nearby BLE devices
async def main():
  async with BleakScanner() as scanner:
      devices = await scanner.discover()
      for d in devices:
          print(d)

# defining the connection function
async def client_connect():

# connecting with the Nano BLE 33's corresponding MAC address
        async with BleakClient("c7:5a:cc:5e:59:69") as client:
            if client.is_connected:
                (f"connected to {client.address}")
            else:
                print("failed to connect to client")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
    asyncio.run(client_connect())
```

I have tried altering the threshold of the timeout for the client_connect function up to 30 seconds but I am still getting the same timeout. I also tried changing the wait time between pin reads on the Arduino in case that was impacting the connection but I am still getting the same error message. The `(f"connected to {client.address}")` statements never appear in the terminal leading me to believe it never makes it to checking if the client is connected.

Versions
Python: 3.10
Bleak: 0.20.1
Windows: 11
Arduino IDE: 2.0.4